# How to register a django model field with any type?

Tags: python, django, django-models, models

I have built an API With Django REST Framework. On client side I use Angular and I have an class that looks like:

```
export class Property{
  id: number;
  value: any;                                                          
}
```

The value property can take many variables with many types: string, array or number...
How can I save value with my API?

```
from django.db import models                                      
class Property(models.Model):
    value = ?
```

I've looked a bit. I found Django Generic's relations. But I have no idea how to use it.

Can you help me?

Comment: You're thinking along the wrong lines. Django's model fields dictate the type of column used to store the data in the database. So, how you want to store your data?

Comment: I want to store data with any type. I fix this with JSONField.

Comment: But you didn't answer the question. Database columns have types. Which one do you want to use?

Comment: Finally, the best answer is to use CharField as Rodriguez said. I modify the client side before saving the property value to the database. Number, Boolean, Array are transforming into String before putting them to API and I do the reverse operation when I get a response from the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python doesn't have an 'any' type like typescript! However.. I sometimes use Charfield on models when a value may be generic.. It is not so much generic but consider that your model must map a database.. And databases don't have generic types of values

Answer (score 0):

Well what you can declare as [any type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#the-any-type) is python variables and properties. Where things get problematic is Database, which usually requires exact data types for specific fields.

If you really need any type to be stored in database, you can use Django's [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField).

In this field you can store dict, list and usually string or integer... but this is highly dependent on database you are using.